# BPMN 2.0. How to make an existing sub-process multiple?

Tags: bpmn

I have sub-process. What is the right way to make it multiple? 1 or 2?

[image]

Comment: please have a look at my answer and provide me with some feedback so that we could close this issue for you and for anyone who might come across this in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have your `start` and `end` events inside the `task`, so the second option is fine.

Reference: page 191 of the PDF spec http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/